# How to implement an Antisymmetric Function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to test whether the relations (pairs) of the set are antisymmetric meaning:
    a binary relation R on a set X is antisymmetric if, for all a and b in X
      if R(a,b) and R(b,a), then a = b,
    or, equivalently,
      if R(a,b) with a ≠ b, then R(b,a) must not hold.

```
antisymetric: 
 set holds to true
 for each pair(e,f) in b
    if pair(f,e) is in b
        if f is not e
            set holds to false
            break
```

What am I doing wrong??

Here is my function along with a sample test in the main:

```
void antiSymmetric(int b[], int sizeOfB)
{
bool hold = true; // set hold to true
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfB;) // for each pair (e,f) in b
{
    if(hold == false)
    {
        cout << "AntiSymmetric - No" << endl; 
        break; //Did not find (e,e) in b
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeOfB;)
    {
        if(b[i] == b[j+1] && b[i+1] == b[j]) //If true, then pair(f,e) exists
        {
            if(b[i+1] != b[i]) //If true, relation is antisymmetric
            {
                hold = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hold = false;
                j = j + 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hold = false;
            j = j + 2;
        }

    }
    i = i + 2;

}
if(hold == true)
    cout << "AntiSymmetric - Yes" << endl;

}

int main()
{
    int set4[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int rel4[20] = {1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4,
                    7, 5, 8, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2);

    cout << "Set 4: " << endl;
    antiSymmetric(rel4, 20);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the increments at the bottom of the loop rather than in the loop statment like `for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfB; ++i)`? Also you seem to be doing at least twice as much work as you need to...

Comment: @dmckee: I was trying to follow antisymmetric:
    set holds to true....
    for each pair(e,f) in b....
        if pair(f,e) is in b...
            if f is not e...
                set holds to false...
                break...

Comment: Backticks for in-line code... `

Comment: Checking for transitivity and checking for antisymmetry are different things. Are you trying to learn if *both* hold?

Comment: I'm sorry that is for a separate function.  I re-posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `b` array is `{ 1, 2,   3, 4 }`.  When `i == 0` and `j == 2`, the condition `b[i] == b[j+1] && b[i+1] == b[j]` reduces to `1 == 4 && 2 == 3`, which is false.  So you take the `else` branch and set `hold = false`.  But that test did not disprove the antisymmetry of the set.  You set `hold` incorrectly in that case.